# get by category id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, class, categories

thanks for helps for my last question
I have a problem with my project in Topic class for view all the topics in a special category
Check out my Function in the 'Topic' class:

```
/*
 * Get topics by Category
 */
public function getByCategory($category_id){
    $this->db->query("SELECT topics.*, categories.*, users.username, users.avatar FROM topics
                        INNER JOIN categories
                        ON topics.category_id = categories.id
                        INNER JOIN users
                        ON topics.user_id = users.id
                        WHERE topics.category_id = :category_id
    ");
    $his->db->bind(':category_id', $category_id);

    //Assign Result Set
    $results = $this->db->resultset();

    return $results;

}
```

And this is my topics.php in the root folder

```
<?php   require('core/init.php');?>
<?php
//create New Topic
$topic = new Topic;

//Get Category From URL
$category = isset($_GET['category']) ? $_GET['category'] : null;

//Get user From URL
$user_id = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : null;

//Get Template & Assign Vars
$template = new Template('templates/topics.php');

//Assign Template Variables
if(isset($category)){
    $template->topics = $topic->getByCategory($category);
    $template->title = 'Posts In "'.$topic->getByCategory($category)->name.'"';
}

//Assign Template Variables
if(isset($user_id)){
    $template->topics = $topic->getByUser($user_id);
    $template->title = 'Posts By "'.$topic->getUser($user_id)->username.'"';
}


if(!isset($category) && !isset($user_id)){
    $template->topics = $topic->getAllTopics();
}

//Assign vars

$template->totalTopics = $topic->getTotalTopics();
$template->totalCategories = $topic->getTotalCategories();

// display Template
echo $template;

?>
```

when i click on a category link ('topics.php?category=1') it has This Error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: his in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\talkingspace\libraries\Topic.php on line 74
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\talkingspace\libraries\Topic.php on line 74
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\talkingspace\libraries\Topic.php on line 74

I think maybe I failed in the Query for SELECT from DB.

Best Regards for Any Helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct this line

```
$his->db->bind(':category_id', $category_id);
```

It would be `$this` not `$his`

```
$this->db->bind(':category_id', $category_id);
```

Comment: you are welcome @AliQorbani !! enjoy

Answer (score 3):

Modify `$his` to `$this` in Topic Class's `getByCategory()` function.